# BeautifulSoup uncomment a comment by id

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to use BeautifulSoup to change a html below to uncomment by comment tag id.

```
<div class="foo">
 cat dog sheep goat
 <!--<p id="p1">test</p>-->
 <p id="p2">
  test
 </p>
</div>
```

This is my expected result below:

```
<div class="foo">
 cat dog sheep goat
 <p id="p1">test</p>
 <p id="p2">
  test
 </p>
</div>
```

This is my python code I use BeautifulSoup, but I don't know how to complete this function.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Comment

data = """<div class="foo">
cat dog sheep goat
<p id='p1'>test</p>
<p id='p2'>test</p>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for comment in soup(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    if 'id="p1"' in comment.string: 
        # I don't know how to complete it here.
        # This is my incorrect solution
        # It will output "&lt;p id="p1"&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;",
        # not "<p id='p1'>test</p>"    
        comment.replace_with(comment.string.replace("<!--", "").replace("-->", ""))  
        break
```

Ask for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put new soup to `.replace_with()` instead of string:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Comment

data = """<div class="foo">
 cat dog sheep goat
 <!--<p id="p1">test</p>-->
 <p id="p2">
  test
 </p>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print('Original soup:')
print('-' * 80)
print(soup)
print()

for comment in soup(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    if 'id="p1"' in comment.string:
        tag = BeautifulSoup(comment, 'html.parser')
        comment.replace_with(tag)
        break

print('New soup:')
print('-' * 80)
print(soup)
print()
```

Prints:

```
Original soup:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="foo">
 cat dog sheep goat
 <!--<p id="p1">test</p>-->
<p id="p2">
  test
 </p>
</div>

New soup:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="foo">
 cat dog sheep goat
 <p id="p1">test</p>
<p id="p2">
  test
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using regex instead of bs4?

Maybe this can get you started.

```py
>>> re.search("<!--((.*)p1(.*))-->", '<!--<p id="p1">test</p>-->')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 26), match='<!--<p id="p1">test</p>-->'>
>>> re.search("<!--((.*)p1(.*))-->", '<!--<p id="p1">test</p>-->').group(1)
'<p id="p1">test</p>'
>>> regex = re.compile("<!--((.*)p1(.*))-->")
>>> regex.sub('<p id="p1">test</p>', '<!--<p id="p1">test</p>-->')
'<p id="p1">test</p>'
```